# React native progressive web app apple-touch-icon not rendering? (using expo)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, progressive-web-apps, apple-touch-icon

I'm having trouble getting the apple-touch-icon to render for a react native progressive web app built with expo. As noted in https://docs.expo.dev/guides/progressive-web-apps/, expo automatically generates the progressive web app assets, and they seem to be generated correctly. They work on android.

The apple-touch-icon is indicated correctly in web-build/index.html:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/pwa/apple-touch-icon/apple-touch-icon-180.png">
```

Full web-build/index.html file contents:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta httpequiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.00001,viewport-fit=cover"/><title>walkthrough</title><style>#root,body,html{width:100%;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100%}#root{flex-shrink:0;flex-basis:auto;flex-grow:1;display:flex;flex:1}html{scroll-behavior:smooth;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;height:calc(100% + env(safe-area-inset-top))}body{display:flex;overflow-y:auto;overscroll-behavior-y:none;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar}</style><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32.png"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="walkthrough"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/pwa/apple-touch-icon/apple-touch-icon-180.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1136.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1242x2688.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-828x1792.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1125x2436.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1242x2208.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-750x1334.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-2048x2732.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1668x2388.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1668x2224.png"><link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="/pwa/apple-touch-startup-image/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2048.png"></head><body><noscript><form action="" style="background-color:#fff;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:9999"><div style="font-size:18px;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:24px;margin:10%;width:80%"><p>Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.</p><p style="margin:20px 0"><button type="submit" style="background-color:#4630eb;border-radius:100px;border:none;box-shadow:none;color:#fff;cursor:pointer;font-weight:700;line-height:20px;padding:6px 16px">Reload</button></p></div></form></noscript><div id="root"></div><script src="/static/js/runtime~app.2e9f1821.js"></script><script src="/static/js/2.326b9420.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/app.985a0d88.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

web-build/manifest.json file:

```
{
  "background_color": "#343751",
  "display": "standalone",
  "lang": "en",
  "name": "walkthrough",
  "short_name": "walkthrough",
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=web_app_manifest",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/pwa/chrome-icon/chrome-icon-144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/pwa/chrome-icon/chrome-icon-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/pwa/chrome-icon/chrome-icon-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

When adding the progressive web app to the home screen on iOS though, I get a screenshot of the app's first screen as the icon, which is not ideal.

Does anyone have a hunch on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `link` tag nested under `head`? Also, can we see the manifest.json file that was generated?

Comment: Yep the link tag is in web-build/index.html, which is: